# Set brightness and other attributes for laptop using ATI Radeon driver from Ubuntu 11.04 repository

Tags: ubuntu, amd-radeon, brightness

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 on Dell Studio laptop with ATI 5470 card. I have set the brightness to a level say 47%. But Each time I login brightness has already become maximum and I have to adjust using brightness key on laptop. Although just by pressing once the brightness adjusts to the 47% as mentioned. I think its because of some setting in ATI driver from repository.